# postfix is appending dns suffix

Tags: email, postfix, centos-7

When I attempt to send a message via postfix, my configuration uses a relayhost:

`relayhost = mail.example.local`

I can do an nslookup on this record, but when I attempt to send a message via postfix, the maillog shows an error:

> Jul 22 23:57:50 unity02 postfix/smtp[92871]: 0052580742C: to=, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=192.168.1.10.example.local type=AAAA: Host not found)

Why is the dns suffix being appended to the relayhost?

My postfix version is 2.10.1 and this is running on CentOS 7.2.1511

Comment: Can you check with `host 192.168.1.10` and `host mail.example.com` to see if the DNS records are correct?

Comment: mail.example.com is 192.168.1.10 and it is pingable. Other Cent 6 servers use it for mail relay.

Comment: Ok. Could you post the output of the hos commands run on the server where it does not work.